# Cannot read property of 'replace' of undefined at window.onscroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

I get the following error on mobile devices only

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
    at window.onscroll
```

Here is the code causing the error

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    window.onscroll = function() { 
       var w = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0);
       if (w<660) { 
       var element = $('#livechat-compact-container');
         element.attr('style', element.attr('style').replace(/bottom:[^;]+/g, ''));
         $('#livechat-compact-container').css('bottom','50px');
       }
   };
  });
</script>
```

The element with the id #livechat-compact-container does exist so I am not sure why it would be undefined and only show this error on mobile.

Comment: It is possible that this code is trying to run before the element is loaded.  Is there a way to only run it after load of that element?

Comment: your `livechat-compact-container` generated dynamically?

Comment: What should you expect from `.replace(/bottom:[^;]+/g, ''));` to do?? .. I meant why you need to replace its style while you can just append the new class to it by using `addClass()`

Comment: @DanielH yes it is generated dynamically using a third party app that i do not have control of.

Comment: Is your elements contain style attr

Comment: Just check if `element` exists and it has attribute `style` before you do any changes. Or, much better, do `element.css({'bottom': '50px'});`.

Comment: Well the reason I am doing this is it always gets generated with inline styles ( which are hard to overwrite ) It always has a style attribute when generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure this is gonna work for you:

1st. move `var element = $('#livechat-compact-container');` up

2nd. update your if to `if (w < 660 && element)`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    window.onscroll = function() {
      var w = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0);
      var element = $('#livechat-compact-container');
      if (w < 660 && element) {
        $('#livechat-compact-container').css('bottom', '50px');
      }
    };
  });
</script>
```

Comment: no that is not going to work if the `#livechat-compact-container` has not a style attribute set.

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli `It always has a style attribute when generated. – chris cozzens 5 mins ago` said by OP

Comment: This is a good start for sure, but I am still actually getting the same error with this.  It has to be something with the style attr, however when i inspect the element it does in fact have a style attribute

Comment: @chriscozzens just skip the removal of `bottom`. No reason to do that. Setting its new value will replace it..

Comment: @chriscozzens hm, then just do `if (w < 660 && element) { $('#livechat-compact-container').css('bottom', '50px');`
      }

Comment: @chriscozzens because you still need to check if the element exists yet.

Comment: Thanks for the help @DanielH  its working now. Cheers

Comment: @chriscozzens The reason that removes`attr('style')` from is not working, the first time you scroll it removed it from style, the next time you scroll it is gone and you have nothing to remove. good luck coding

Answer (score 1):

That is because, as the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr1) says

> As of jQuery 1.6, the `.attr()` method returns `undefined` for attributes that have not been set.

So the issue is not if the element is found, but if it has a `style` attribute set.

The important thing, though, is that you do not have to delete the `bottom` from the style attribute. Just set its new value and it will be done.

```
if (w<660) { 
     var element = $('#livechat-compact-container');
     element .css('bottom','50px');
}
```

Comment: I saw this afterwards, this is the solution, thank you for you help as well!

Answer (score 0):

Let jQuery do the style change, just use:

```
element.css({'bottom': '50px'});
```

In your code:

```
window.onscroll = function() { 
    var w = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0);
    if (w<660) { 
        var element = $('#livechat-compact-container');
        element.css({'bottom': '50px'});
    };
};
```

jQuery [css() method](http://api.jquery.com/css/) will:

> set one or more CSS properties for every matched element

So, if there is no `element`, than no matches, **no errors**.